# "xcrun simctl get_app_container" with group identifier not working

Tags: ios, bash, ios-simulator, simctl

it says I can use group identifier to get exactly the group I want:

```bash
➜  ~ xcrun simctl get_app_container booted
Print the path of the installed app's container
Usage: simctl get_app_container <device> <app bundle identifier> [<container>]

container   Optionally specify the container. Defaults to app.
  app                 The .app bundle
  data                The application's data container
  groups              The App Group containers
  <group identifier>  A specific App Group container
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I believe this's the "group identifier":

```bash
➜  ~ xcrun simctl get_app_container booted com.apple.DocumentsApp groups
group.com.apple.DocumentManager /Users/zcfan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E94453B7-DF52-4A88-AE9E-C1A752DFB613/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/4818FE0A-BC9B-4F13-A39C-71C162E76616
group.com.apple.FileProvider.LocalStorage   /Users/zcfan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E94453B7-DF52-4A88-AE9E-C1A752DFB613/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/6EE8B2AE-4CE2-4D07-9198-88E80455FF03
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But if I call with it, simctl just print the help message again:

```bash
➜  ~ xcrun simctl get_app_container booted com.apple.DocumentsApp group.com.apple.FileProvider.LocalStorage
Print the path of the installed app's container
Usage: simctl get_app_container <device> <app bundle identifier> [<container>]

container   Optionally specify the container. Defaults to app.
  app                 The .app bundle
  data                The application's data container
  groups              The App Group containers
  <group identifier>  A specific App Group container
```

I tried other combinations too, same result:

- `xcrun simctl get_app_container booted com.apple.DocumentsApp group group.com.apple.FileProvider.LocalStorage`
- `xcrun simctl get_app_container booted com.apple.DocumentsApp group.com.apple.FileProvider.LocalStorage`
- `xcrun simctl get_app_container booted com.apple.DocumentsApp groups LocalStorage`
- `xcrun simctl get_app_container booted com.apple.DocumentsApp group LocalStorage`
- `xcrun simctl get_app_container booted com.apple.DocumentsApp LocalStorage`
- `xcrun simctl get_app_container booted com.apple.DocumentsApp groups com.apple.FileProvider.LocalStorage`
- `xcrun simctl get_app_container booted com.apple.DocumentsApp group com.apple.FileProvider.LocalStorage`
- `xcrun simctl get_app_container booted com.apple.DocumentsApp com.apple.FileProvider.LocalStorage`

I couldn't find any group identifier demo anywhere, is this option really working? Am I using the wrong identifier? A working demo would be great, thank you.

---

For now I have to manipulate the result of `groups` to get what I want：

```bash
xcrun simctl get_app_container booted com.apple.DocumentsApp groups | grep LocalStorage | awk -F'\t' '{print $2}'
```

It gives me the path of "On My Phone" filesystem of simulator:

[image]

Open it with Finder, I can do whatever I want to simulator FS.

```bash
open "`xcrun simctl get_app_container booted com.apple.DocumentsApp groups | grep LocalStorage | awk -F'\t' '{print $2}'`/File Provider Storage" -a Finder
```

[image]

Comment: No pictures of code please.

Comment: @matt ok, updated

Comment: What is this `com.apple.DocumentsApp` you keep referring to?

Comment: @matt run `xcrun listapps booted` can print all apps in booted simulator, the path of simulator filesystem I need is under this app called `com.apple.DocumentsApp`

Comment: I think you've found a bug. Try reporting it to Apple and let's see what happens. Meanwhile your workaround works (maybe it can be refined, I don't know, but it looks good to me)